# Reset Sequence in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to reset the sequence to 1 dynamically using the following procedure in oracle 11g.

```
create or replace
procedure reset_sequence(p_seq in varchar2)
is
    l_value number;
begin

-- Select the next value of the sequence

    execute immediate
    'select ' || p_seq || 
    '.nextval from dual' INTO l_value;

-- Set a negative increment for the sequence, 
-- with value = the current value of the sequence

    execute immediate
    'alter sequence ' || p_seq || 
    ' increment by -' || l_value || ' minvalue 0';

-- Select once from the sequence, to 
-- take its current value back to 0

    execute immediate
    'select ' || p_seq || 
    '.nextval from dual' INTO l_value;

-- Set the increment back to 1

    execute immediate
    'alter sequence ' || p_seq || 
    ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';
end;
/
```

But when I am trying to execute the procedure to reset the sequence **circle_seq**, I am getting following error

```
BEGIN reset_sequence(vf_circle_seq); END;

                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 22:
PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'CIRCLE_SEQ' not allowed 
           in this context
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

what is wrong in code? is this is not possible in oracle 11g because same code I used in oracle 10g before it worked fine.

Comment: try `BEGIN reset_sequence('vf_circle_seq'); END;`

Comment: yes. It worked fine. I made the mistake. thanks!

Comment: i'll post it as an answer

Comment: "before it worked fine" - falser words have rarely been spoken... :) just kidding, we've all made mistakes like this from time to time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence name should be passed as a string

```
BEGIN 
  reset_sequence('vf_circle_seq'); 
END;
```